# How can I compress images with DropzoneJS use jquery.resizeImage?

Tags: dropzone.js

I am doing compress image when the user drags and drops the file. But I'm getting an error when using resizeImage to reduce when the file size is larger than 500KB

```js
Dropzone.options.{{ str_replace(['_', '-'], '', $name??'') }}UploadForm = {
        //http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration-options
        url:'/admin/media',
        paramName: "files",
        clickable: false,
        // maxFilesize: 5, // MB
        uploadMultiple: false,
        parallelUploads: 100, //số file xử lý song song trên 1 request
        maxFiles: 5, //Tối đa 5 file 1 lần
        acceptedFiles: '.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.svg',
        //autoProcessQueue: false,
        transformFile: function(file, done) {
            let b = new ClipboardEvent("").clipboardData || new DataTransfer();
            // Lớn hơn 500KB thì giảm kích thước
            if (file.size > 512000 || file.fileSize > 512000) {
              new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                resizeImage(file, {
                  use_reader: false,
                  mode: 2,
                  val: 400,
                  type: 'image/jpeg',
                  quality: 0.8,
                  callback: function(result) {
                    let myFile = dataURLtoFile(result, file.name);
                    b.items.add(myFile);
                    resolve();
                  }
                });
              }).then(function() {
                console.log(b.files[0]);
                done(b.files[0]);
              });
            } else {
              b.items.add(file);
              done(b.files[0]);
            }
          },
        accept: function(file, done) {
            done();
        },
        error: function(file, response) {
            console.log('Up-Error: '+response);
        },
        processing: function (file) {
            var imgLoading = Dropzone.createElement('<img class="img-loading" style="position:absolute;top:-20px;left:calc(50% - 8px);z-index:10;" src="/admin_assets/images/loading.gif" />');
            file.previewElement.append(imgLoading);
            $('#image-box-{{$name??''}}').parents('.mb-3').find('.dropzone .dz-message').hide();
            $('.message-full-storage-{{$name??''}}').hide();
        },
        success: function(file,response) {
            if(response.status == -1){
                $('.img-loading').remove();
                $('#image-box-{{$name??''}}').hide();
                $('#image-box-{{$name??''}}').find('input').val('');
                $('#image-box-{{$name??''}}').parents('.mb-3').find('.dropzone').show();
                $('#image-box-{{$name??''}}').parents('.mb-3').find('.dropzone .dz-preview').remove();
                $('#image-box-{{$name??''}}').parents('.mb-3').find('.dropzone .dz-message').show();
                $('.message-full-storage-{{$name??''}}').html(response.message);
                $('.message-full-storage-{{$name??''}}').show();
                return false;
            }
            $('.img-loading').remove();
            console.log('Up-Success:');
            console.log(response);
            $('#image-box-{{$name??''}}').find('img').attr('src', response.link);
            $('#image-box-{{$name??''}}').find('input').val(response.link);
            $('#image-box-{{$name??''}}').show();
            $('#image-box-{{$name??''}}').parents('.mb-3').find('.dropzone').hide();
            $('#image-box-{{$name??''}}').parents('.mb-3').find('.dropzone .dz-message').show();
            $('#image-box-{{$name??''}}').parents('.mb-3').find('.dropzone .dz-preview').remove();
        }
    };
```